# Can't find where does the extra space on the right of my site comes from

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've just noticed that on one of my websites you can scroll horizontally and it's literally empty space on the right of the content. No idea where this comes from. I've tried adding the following CSS, in order to highlight the element that's causing the issue but it didn't:

```
* {
    background: black !important;
}

* * {
    background: pink !important;
}

* * * {
    background: red !important;
}

* * * * {
    background: blue !important;
}

* * * * * {
    background: green !important;
}

* * * * * * {
    background: grey !important;
}

* * * * * * * {
    background: brown !important;
}

* * * * * * * * {
    background: beige !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * {
    background: black !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * {
    background: pink !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: red !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: blue !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: green !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * *  {
    background: grey !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: brown !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: beige !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: lightgreen !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: lightcoral !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: yellow !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: purple !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: rebeccapurple !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: sandybrown !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: saddlebrown !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: navajowhite !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: orange !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: orangered !important;
}

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * {
    background: greenyellow !important;
}
```

You can see the problem [here](https://www.imagecurve.com/).

I don't know how else to debug this.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Comment: I don't know which part is causing the issue so I can't post a minimal reproducible example. If I did I wouldn't have to post here.

Comment: Then you have two problems. When your link changes or disappears altogether, your question becomes useless. That's why such things are not allowed.

Comment: Also, please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Hint.... Your page happends to be around 3.4k pixels wide

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue quickly with this:

```
#wrapper, .container-inner {
    min-width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Below code cause for extra space.
.col-3cm .main-inner{padding-left: 340px;}

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this:

```
html {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```